# how to search records beetween two dates. But table date format is varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, mysqli

I have a table. In which, a column name is `tb_date`, which is `varchar` format. In that column dates are save, But in different-different format (Like: `01/07/201 OR 01-08-2018` or `2017/03/12` etc.).
Now I want a search between given date. But it is not working. I tried it-

```
SELECT * FROM `user_History` WHERE date_format(str_to_date(`tb_date`, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '01/06/2018' AND '31/06/2018'
```

But its giving all record.
I tried it in my sql.

Whats is the problem?

Comment: First, clean up the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your `str_to_date(tb_date, '%d/%m/%Y')`, you give a format `%d/%m/%Y` of importing date, but you have different formats in this field.

I think, you should process all your table by PHP and, for example, convert all your dates to UNIX_TIMESTAMP by function `strtotime()`.

It will be more easy than try to create a SQL query for it.